# Google Play Games loadPlayerCenteredScores exception

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-games

The Game has multiple leaderboards, the app uses `loadPlayerCenteredScores` on startup to swap online scores with local scores.

```
for (lvl in 1..12) {
    // call loadPlayerCenteredScores inside the function
    loopGetUserScore("leaderboard_$lvl")
}
```

On Google Play Games reports, some users(2/1000) crash on `loadPlayerCenteredScores` with the following error message:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Max XP must be more than min XP!
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState (Preconditions.java)
at com.google.android.gms.games.PlayerLevel.<init> (PlayerLevel.java)
at com.google.android.gms.games.PlayerRef.<init> (PlayerRef.java)
at com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.LeaderboardScoreRef.<init> (LeaderboardScoreRef.java)
at com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.LeaderboardScoreBuffer.get (LeaderboardScoreBuffer.java)
```

Only a small percentage of users experience this problem, but it must be fixed. Is It a's a problem of Google side? How can I fixed it or avoid it? Thanks.